# How can I access windows recovery option when dual booting, or do I have any other relatively easy solution?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, shutdown

So, I have windows 10 and ubuntu on my laptop. I was using win10, I shut down the machine, and when I opened it again and tried to enter win10, a black screen with a blinking cursor appeared.

I don't really know why that happened, since I haven't done any changes to my laptop, didn't install anything, etc, it just suddenly decided that it can't boot windows. I don't really know what to do, so I tried to get into windows recovery mode, however I'm not sure how to do that. Technically, I should shut down my laptop right after it starts, and after I do that 3 times, windows should automatically enter recovery mode. However, that didn't really work. I tried shutting it down right as the laptop opened, and it didn't work. I tried shutting it down right after I chose to boot into win10, that didn't work either. I tried shutting it down after the black screen appeared, that didn't work either.

So, how can I enter windows recovery mode when dual booting? And, do you have any other suggestions that I can try besides booting from an USB stick and trying to recover from there or install windows again?

**EDIT:** Now I realized, before shutting it down, I was messing around with *pyinstaller*, and in the process I changed something at **environment variables**, but I didn't remove anything that was already there. Could that have caused anything? I don't think so, but just thought I'll add it here

**EDIT 2:** I made a win10 bootable USB, booted from it, messed a bit around with **start-up repair**, didn't seem like I got anything done, but I tried booting again from the hard drive and it worked... So, I'm not sure why it didn't work before, but at least I fixed it for now. But I still don't know why it didn't work before...

Comment: @Ramhound Within settings where? I can't get on windows at all (or at least I don't know how)

Answer (score 0):

Fix your boot loader should work:
https://www.groovypost.com/howto/fix-windows-10-wont-boot-startup-repair-bootrec/